# jquery is not loading, when loaded from server but works fine when loading externally

Tags: jquery, tomcat

Jquery is not loading in tomcat, When I'm using from the server,which is outside the WEB-INF:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="common/js/library/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

But the below is

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src=” https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
```

is loading fine.

When I'm accessing the jquery-1.11.0.js in the first case in sources of firebug or in chrome debuggers as shown as in below image.

[image]

It seems to be loading but when I'm clicking on the loaded jquery-1.11.0.js file nothing seems to load the js file.

I'd given full access to the file system in linux. Whats wrong.

Comment: Click "Network" and find the js file, did it load correctly?

Comment: yes fine. GET 200 Ok. but at $ or jQuery uncaught error in js code.

Comment: what the respon ? is same with jquery script ? or maybe another like something routing url is available.

Comment: no script from the server is not loading.

Comment: When I'm clicking on the  jquery-1.11.0.js file it is targetting to the same jsp file which is loading.

Comment: Seems a little strange to have a slash in the directory name "common/js". I believe that is a [reserved character](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/). Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
some how I mistakenly typed `servlet-mapping to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you loading this script?